# Phonegap native photo viewer

Tags: cordova, photo-gallery

I'm developing a phonegap app and I need a way of displaying images more like the native photo viewer.

All i found are couple of obj.c plugins, but i don't have the knowledge of doing this.

There is any phonegap plugin to emulate this?

Thanks!